# how do I sort a array of text by the last numberic character in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a array of texts, such as this `[building2, building1 , building3, building5, building4]`.

How do I sort this array by the last numeric character, so the sorted out array will be `building1, building2, building3, building4, building5, building6`?

Comment: For your specific example, `.sort()` suffices. If you need something else, your example needs to be good enough to disqualify the obvious solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "last numberic[sic] character"? Do you really mean that foo10 should come before foo9 because `0` < `9`? Or do you actually want to compare the numeric values `10` vs `9`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var array = ["building200", "building10", "building3", "building5", "building4"];

array.sort(function(a, b){
  var char1 = a.substr(a.search(/\d+$/));  // get the last numbers
  var char2 = b.substr(b.search(/\d+$/));   // get the last numbers
  return parseInt(char1) - parseInt(char2); // sort by parsing to number
});

alert(array); // ["building3", "building4", "building5", "building10", "building200"]
```

`a.search(/\d/)` will return index of first digit encountered, and `a.substr(that_index)` will cut string from there till the end.

Will also work if array has strings of uneven length like `["buildingsss2", "buildisng1", "building3", "building5", "builsding4"]`

Hope that helps!

Comment: @RoyiNamir I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean. Could you please explain a little more. Thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir But I also want my function to work on strings of different length, so this might not work. Thanks though :)

Comment: got confused with `a` . thought it meant array (insted of the value itself) deleting stupid comment

Comment: p.s what about `building10` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir The OP wants the "last numeric character", though I also believe that 9 should come before 10 (which my program reverses). I am waiting for clarification from OP or I think I might add that right now.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I have updated my answer. Please go through it more carefully. I use it to find the first occurrence and then extract the string from there till the end.

Comment: I wasnt talking about this : `building100` I was talking about this :`100building100`

Comment: @RoyiNamir I am extremely sorry. Please don't mind. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regular expression `\d+` to get all the consecutive numbers and then compare the two elements by substracting one from the other, like this

```
var data = [ 'building2', 'building10', 'building3', 'building5', 'building4' ];

data.sort(function(first, second) {
    return /\d+/.exec(first)[0] - /\d+/.exec(second)[0];
});

console.log(data);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'building2', 'building3', 'building4', 'building5', 'building10' ]
```

**Note:** This is better than the other solutions posted till now, as this will work fine even if the numbers are greater than 9.

Comment: you should add the `$` to the regex so it match the actual last number  , so you wont fail in `100building100` ( and I know the OP didnt mentio it , but we should supply robust code.

Answer (score 2):

Use .sort() method

```
var a = ['building2', 'building1' , 'building3', 'building5', 'building4'];
console.log(a.sort());
```

Output

```
["building1", "building2", "building3", "building4", "building5"]
```

Is not needed a custom function

Answer (score 2):

`Array.sort`, using:

```
['building2', 'building1', 'building3', 'building5', 'building4']. 
  sort(function(a,b){
         return +( /\d{1,}$/.exec(a) || [0] )[0] - 
                +( /\d{1,}$/.exec(a) || [0] )[0]; 
       }
  );
```

That way you can also sort on more then 10 buildings like in
`['building1', 'building12', 'building302', 'building205', 'building400']`
and include strings not ending with numeric values

Comment: +1 best so far. ( both finding numbers  AND that appear LAST)